# vba ".Remove key" method only put Empty to the corresponding Dictionary item

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary of fixations, a custom class containing informations about the fixation:

```
master as long
slave as long
model as string
mcomp as collection
scomp as collection
```

The key (`fixationkey as string`) is built using: `fixation.master & fixation.slave & fixation.model & mcomps` (mcomps being a string of all vector components bind by this fixation put together).
It appears that some fixations in this dictionary have the same master, the same slave and the same model. Only the components differ. What I want to do is regroup these fixations in one with all components.
So I implemented this method:

```
Sub detectfixationsdoubles()
''Detect fixation that are similar: same master node, same slave node, same model but with different comps
''Merge these fixations
    Dim fixationkey as string
    Dim fixationcompared As Variant
    Dim fixationcomparedto As Variant
    Dim newfixation As fixation
    Dim compitem As Variant

    'First loop on the fixations: each fixation is compared
    For Each fixationcompared In Cfixationstreat.Items
        'Second loop on the fixations : each fixation is compared to all the fixations
        For Each fixationcomparedto In Cfixationstreat.Items
            If fixationcompared.master = fixationcomparedto.master _
                    And fixationcompared.slave = fixationcomparedto.slave _
                    And fixationcompared.model = fixationcomparedto.model Then
                If Not fixationcompared Is fixationcomparedto Then
                    Set newfixation = New fixation
                    Set newfixation = fixationcompared

                    With fixationcompared
                        fixationkey = .master & .slave & .model
                        For Each compitem In .mcomp
                            fixationkey = fixationkey & compitem
                        Next
                    End With

                    Cfixationstreat.Remove fixationkey
                    fixationcompared = Empty

                    With fixationcomparedto
                        For Each compitem In .mcomp
                            newfixation.mcompadd compitem
                        Next
                        For Each compitem In .scomp
                            newfixation.scompadd compitem
                        Next

                        fixationkey = .master & .slave & .model
                        For Each compitem In .mcomp
                            fixationkey = fixationkey & compitem
                        Next
                    End With

                    Cfixationstreat.Remove (fixationkey)
                    fixationcomparedto = Empty

                    With newfixation
                        fixationkey = .master & .slave & .model
                        For Each compitem In .mcomp
                            fixationkey = fixationkey & compitem
                        Next
                    End With

                    Cfixationstreat.Add fixationkey, newfixation
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

However what I see is that the 2 fixations that I want to remove are still in the Dictionary. The key is still present but associated with `Empty`.
Is that a problem from excel(i'm using excel 2007)? Is that a problem due to objects (i still have problems with pointers)? Have I done any syntax error?

Thanks for any help.

PS: if you see any way to increase the speed of this method, it would help. Right now it is time consuming, even with medium sized dictionaries...

Answer (score 0):

My bad! Sorry for people that tried to find an answer. I had a spy with : Cfixationtreat(fixationkey).
I believe this is why the key is not totaly removed.